# Python writing to JSON file

Tags: python, json, discord.py

Issue am facing here is that in my code there are many functions which are dumping data in a json file simultaneously like,

```
""" Data of the JSON file is like
   {"Channels": [],1:[],2:[]} """

def update_channels():
 with open(file,'r') as f:
  data = json.load(f)
 data["Channels"].append(stuff)
 with open(file,'w') as f:
  json.dump(data,f)

def update_key(key_no):
 with open(file,'r') as f:
  data = json.load(f)
 data[key_no].append(stuff)
 with open(file,'w') as f:
  json.dump(data,f)
```

These update functions are triggered by events and there can be cases where they are executed at the same time or within no time gap so, data of that JSON file can be overlapped causing loss of data.

How can I resolve this problem? Basically, this is for a discord bot and these functions will be triggered by discord events.

Thanks!

Comment: Are these functions run in threads, or multiple instances of this program in parallel? Then you’ll want to use *advisory locks*: https://docs.python.org/3/library/fcntl.html

Comment: There is a simple solution to your issue. **Stop using JSON as a database.** Use a database as a database. Python comes with built-in SQLite support (`import sqlite3`). Set up a database and store your data there. It's not harder than using JSON, it's more versatile, it's faster, and it does not suffer from race conditions like this one.

Comment: @deceze These functions are triggered by the discord events, so for instance if there is a case where two people react with an emoji at the same time, then yea these functions will be executed parallelly.

Comment: I don’t know how the discord client works exactly, whether it does implicit threading or not…

Comment: @Tomalak I got your point, but really for that I've to fully change my code line by line as currently it's fully working on JSON, isn't there a solution for this particular issue? I'll shift to sqlite later on.

Comment: No you won't. If you don't shift now, you will keep tacking on kludges because it's always "just one kludge away from perfection". JSON is a *horrible* choice for doing what you're doing. Every kludge you add will make it harder to redo your storage layer. You're not spending your time wisely by working around issues like this, because the only reason you have those issues in the first place is because you made an unsustainable design choice.

Comment: Now that I think about it, this should not be an issue, since AFAIK a Discord client runs in an event loop. There should not be a case where code is run simultaneously even if two clients send something at the same time.

Comment: @Amadan I've faced this issue personally that's why I thought of asking this, for instance I had a function in which a value was increased by 1 each time that function was called, which is to be stored in JSON afterwards, so I tried triggering multiple instances of that function myself with multiple phones, by opening discord and reacting with an emoji at the same time, but that value wasn't increased by 1 each time I reacted, like If I reacted with 2 phones simultaneously then the value was increased by only 1 while it was expected to be increased by 2.

Comment: Using database will fix this problem? Even if I update the database myself live by opening it. Like, the code is running and if I opened the database and made some changes in it and then saved it, then will this cause any loss of data or it'll safe each time?

Comment: Also can anyone of you please look onto my other question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67234531/python-asynchronous-functions#

Comment: Yes, using a database will fix the issue, because databases do not work like flat files. They guarantee transactional and referential integrity, that's their fundamental design goal.

Comment: One doubt, in my case do I need to create a new connection each time while updating the database like creating a new connection in each of the function or just creating a single connection at start will work? Also is it necessary to close the connection?                                                                              Note : There are many updating functions in my programme

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this. One is to use a database, which will do access control for you. Another one is to use a lock. But the simplest one is to leave it to the kernel: write to a temporary file, then replace the original atomically. I.e. to write a file, do this instead:

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import os

dirname = os.dirname(file)
with NamedTemporaryFile(dir=dirname, delete=False) as temp:
    json.dump(data, temp)
    temp.close()
    os.replace(temp.name, file)
```

Python guarantees that nothing will interrupt `os.replace`.

EDIT: This merely answers the question as posed; but I fully agree with comments saying a database is the right choice.